# Adding thumbs up/down to Tumblr Page

Tags: html, tumblr, rating

Wanting to add a thumbs up/down rating system to my Tumblr Page, just like how fmylife.com and textfromlastnight.com have. Any ideas of how this can be added or if anyone has done this before successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tumblr doesn't have an up/down rating system built in, so if it exists, it would need to be an external site that stores the ratings.

Tumblr *does* have an up-only rating system, called Likes. You could use a thumb icon to style it. I created a Tumblr to explain how to setup a Like button in a theme: http://like-button.tumblr.com/

To add Like functionality, you use the following URL and set it as the `src` attribute of an invisible `<iframe>`:

```
http://www.tumblr.com/<command>/<oauthId>?id=<postId>
```

- `<command>`: `like` or `unlike`
- `<oauthId>`: last eight characters of `{ReblogURL}`
- `<postId>`: `{PostID}`

Example:

```
http://www.tumblr.com/like/fGKvAJgQ?id=16664837215
```

You need to put both variables, `{ReblogURL}` and `{PostID}`, into your `{block:Posts}` block. Then use script to build the URL and set the `src`.

Script:

```js
$( document ).on( 'click', '.like', function ( event ) {

event.preventDefault();

var command = $( this ).hasClass( 'liked' ) ? 'unlike' : 'like',
    post = $( this ).closest( '.post' ),
    oauth = post.find( '.reblog' ).attr( 'href' ).slice( -8 ),
    id = post.attr( 'id' ),
    likeUrl = 'http://www.tumblr.com/' + command + '/' + oauth + '?id=' + id;

$( '#like-it' ).attr( 'src', likeUrl );
$( this ).toggleClass( 'liked' );

} );
```

HTML:

```html
{block:Posts}
<article id="{PostID}">
<a href="{ReblogURL}" class="reblog">reblog</a>
<a href="#" class="like">like</a>
</article>
{block:Posts}

<iframe id="like-it"></iframe>
```

CSS:

```css
#like-it {
    display: none;
}

.liked, .like:hover {
    color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! this worked perfectly! appreciate the time and effort you put into this.